# Issue on Remote Desktop connection

Tags: windows, connection, gateway

"I'm encountering an issue while attempting to connect to remote desktop. The error message states, 'This computer cannot authenticate the RD Gateway server "***********". it is not safe to connect to unspecified servers.' How can I bypass this issue?"